# Why does spark write huge file into temporary local disk even without on-disk persist or checkpoint?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, persist, checkpoint

I'm running a small job on a cluster with 15G of mem and 8G of disk per machine.

The job always get into a deadlock where the last error message is:

```
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:345)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter$TimeTrackingOutputStream$$anonfun$write$3.apply$mcV$sp(BlockObjectWriter.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.org$apache$spark$storage$DiskBlockObjectWriter$$callWithTiming(BlockObjectWriter.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter$TimeTrackingOutputStream.write(BlockObjectWriter.scala:86)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.dumpOutput(SnappyOutputStream.java:300)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.rawWrite(SnappyOutputStream.java:247)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.write(SnappyOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1876)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeByte(ObjectOutputStream.java:1914)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:350)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(BlockObjectWriter.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter$$anonfun$writePartitionedFile$4$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExternalSorter.scala:751)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter$$anonfun$writePartitionedFile$4$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExternalSorter.scala:750)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter$$anonfun$writePartitionedFile$4.apply(ExternalSorter.scala:750)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter$$anonfun$writePartitionedFile$4.apply(ExternalSorter.scala:746)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.writePartitionedFile(ExternalSorter.scala:746)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

By the time it happens the shuffle write size is 0.0B and input size is 3.4MB. I wonder what operation could quickly eat up the entire 5G free disk space.

In addition, The storage level of the entire job is confined to MEMORY_ONLY_SERIALIZED and checkpointing is completely disabled.

Comment: This is likely going to happen if your data doesn't fit in memory. Also, Spark has to write to disk for any kind of shuffle operations (e.g., reduce). 

To verify if input size is causing an issue I would suggest you use a much *smaller* input dataset and see if you get this error or not.

Comment: I've already tried and it does pass the test. But in either case the size of my data is way below the total memory (300G+, while my largest dataset is about 4G - as you can already see in "shuffle size" metric)

Comment: Spark also persists to reduce the need to recalculate from scratch if a node is lost.

Comment: only see the reversed situation occurs: when persisted on slow network it still do the recalculation if it is way faster. IMHO persist/checkpointing can only be invoked manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the shuffle operations fit in memory, you can try setting 
spark.shuffle.spill to false. (otherwise you get OOM).
At http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html you can see the options concerning shuffle behavior and the other public configuration options.

The MEMORY_ONLY_SERIALIZED applies to RDDs.

Comment: Actually, even if the shuffle fits in memory it would still be written after the hash/sort phase of the shuffle. Spark simply doesn't hold this in memory, counter to common knowledge. The `spark.shuffle.spill` parameter only matters during (not after) the hash/sort phase. In fact, the parameter doesn't do much at all since spark 1.5.1. This is the most enlightening thread for me in the last year: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-dev/201604.mbox/%3c53D611B1-CC86-4BA5-AEA8-0004F29AD2D5@gmail.com%3e I'm still thinking of adding it to the official documentation when I have the time.